# Why can't I see my close vote?

Tags: soporte, votos-de-cierre

I voted to close [How to convey in Spanish "That is flattering" with positive connotations?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30262/9385) because there aren't any sample sentences with a blank where the word would go, to show us how to use the word.  But next to the "close" link, there's no

> (1)

which I'd expect to see.

I can't vote to close because the system says I voted to close too recently.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: While that question doesn't have "sample sentences with a blank where the word would go", it has sample sentences including the original word. There's 3 examples using the word we are trying to look for an equivalent in Spanish. Why would those not work to illustrate the same as the sample sentences with the blank?

Comment: @Diego - I wouldn't necessarily use the same word in those three examples.  They're actually pretty different.  Sometimes when trying to go from one language to another, one needs to use a work-around.  It's incredibly helpful to understand in what situation exactly you're feeling a gap in your ability to express something equivalent to "flattering" in your other main language.

Answer (score 3):

Your vote aged away.

Once your vote was cast, a review item was created in the Close review queue:

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/close/17441

The review item was completed after it got three 'Leave Open' votes.

You can read more about how close votes age away in:

- [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/209901) to *How do close votes age away?*, which links to
- [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/209901)

Basically, votes age away after some time, this time depending on how many views the question gets. In your case, your vote to close was cast on Apr 27 and aged away by May 2 (info only moderators can see).

---

In general, if you vote to close it is normally interesting explain why, so others looking at the question may know about the reasoning that led you to do so.